# How can i persist data in react native application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, sqlite, react-native

I want to create a React Native app that persists local data and then syncs to the server. Please help me to find a way for this.

Comment: Consider reading some tutorials and making an attempt at solving the problem before asking.

Comment: @kreld yes I am working on app which takes an offline survey and then with sync data will be uploaded to the server. So want to know what to use in react for offline database management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native provides methods to persist data. Some are provided out of the box while others are libraries you have to install and use. Below are popular methods of persisting data in React Native

- AsyncStorage
- React Native SQLite 2
- Realm
- React Native Local MongoDB

refer https://pusher.com/tutorials/persisting-data-react-native

Answer (score 0):

For persisting data on your platform `iOS / Android` I would recommend to use `AsyncStorage`.

Check out the `documentation`.

[AsyncStorage-ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

Then for `sync` for the server you have to manage your data I guess with your data persisting `diagram`.

> SET DATA

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

> GET DATA

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Then when you set a data to the phone, make a `Network` call with `fetch()` api of the `React Native`, then do your `sync` job with your backend.

Answer (score 0):

For persisting data locally use realm. Read the documentation from
https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

Before using Realm, please do check your node version. Currently realm only support node V8 and V10. Like I am currently working on node V11.5, I don't want to downgrade my node.

React Native Local MongoDB is *Deprecated* , I think there will be no further enhancement and support for this library. Do check https://github.com/antoniopresto/react-native-local-mongodb